# What is the most performant way to check if each character in a string is present in a predefined set of characters?

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, performance, validation

What is the best way to check if each character in a string is present in a predefined set of characters?
The predefined set of characters is defined as `"0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"`.

The below works fine, but is there a better way to handle this?

```
 For X As Int32 = 0 To stringVal.Length - 1
    If PredefinedCharacters.IndexOf(stringVal.Chars(X)) = -1 Then
        'Invalid value
         Return False
    End If
 Next X
```

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `String` to store a list of invalid characters means a [linear search](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) through that `String` for each `Char` being tested in the input `String`.  This is inefficient.

A [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) provides an efficient way of looking up if values exist in, as you put it, a "set" of characters:

```
Shared ReadOnly PredefinedCharacters As HashSet(Of Char) = New HashSet(Of Char)(
    "0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"
)

Shared Function IsValid(stringVal As String) As Boolean
    REM Optional: Reject null/empty input
    REM If String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVal) Then
    REM     Return False
    REM End If

    For X As Int32 = 0 To stringVal.Length - 1
        If Not PredefinedCharacters.Contains(stringVal.Chars(X)) Then
            'Invalid value
            Return False
        End If
    Next X

    Return True
End Function
```

Here's some code I wrote using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) comparing the use of a `HashSet`, `Regex` (compiled and not), and some other methods:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes

REM None should really be the default value of this enumeration,
REM but this is the only way to have it benchmarked last
Public Enum TextAdjustment
    FirstCharInvalid
    MiddleCharInvalid
    None
End Enum

Public Class Benchmarks
    Private Const ValidCharsString As String = "0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"
    Private Shared ReadOnly ValidCharsHashSet As New HashSet(Of Char)(ValidCharsString)

    Private Const ValidCharsRegexString As String = "^[0-9A-Za-z\-]+$"
    Private Shared ReadOnly ValidCharsRegexInterpreted As New Regex(ValidCharsRegexString, RegexOptions.None)
    Private Shared ReadOnly ValidCharsRegexCompiled As New Regex(ValidCharsRegexString, RegexOptions.Compiled)

    Const AdjustmentInvalidChar As Char = "~"c

    Shared Sub New()
        REM Short text  (16 characters): Repeat <upper> <lower> <digit> <upper> <lower> <digit> <dash>
        Const shortText As String = "Ab3De6-Hi0Kl3-Op"
        REM Medium text (64 characters): <all upper> <dash> <all lower> <dash> <all digit>
        Const mediumText As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-1234567890"
        Dim longText As String = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(mediumText, 16))
        Dim hugeText As String = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(longText, 1024))
        Dim allText As String() = {shortText, mediumText, longText, hugeText}

        TextByLengthThenAdjustment = allText.ToDictionary(
            Function(text) text.Length,
            Function(text) [Enum].GetValues(GetType(TextAdjustment)) _
                .Cast(Of TextAdjustment) _
                .ToDictionary(
                    Function(adjustment) adjustment,
                    Function(adjustment) GetAdjustedText(text, adjustment)
                )
        )
        TextLengths = Array.AsReadOnly(
            allText.Select(Function(text) text.Length).ToArray()
        )
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>All benchmark text inputs accessed by length then by adjustment.</summary>
    Private Shared ReadOnly Property TextByLengthThenAdjustment As Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of TextAdjustment, String))

    ''' <summary>The lengths of all benchmark text inputs.</summary>
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property TextLengths As IReadOnlyCollection(Of Integer)

    ''' <summary>The length of the current benchmark text input.</summary>
    <ParamsSource(NameOf(TextLengths))>
    Public Property TextLength As Integer

    ''' <summary>The adjustment applied to the current benchmark text input.</summary>
    <ParamsAllValues()>
    Public Property TextAdjustment As TextAdjustment

    ''' <summary>The current benchmark text input, based on the <c>TextLength</c> and <c>TextAdjustment</c> parameters.</summary>
    Private Property Text As String

    ''' <summary>Gets the specified text with the specified adjustment applied.</summary>
    ''' <param name="text">The text to be adjusted.</param>
    ''' <param name="adjustment">The adjustment to apply.</param>
    ''' <returns>The adjusted text.</returns>
    Private Shared Function GetAdjustedText(text As String, adjustment As TextAdjustment) As String
        Select Case adjustment
            Case TextAdjustment.None
                Return text
            Case TextAdjustment.FirstCharInvalid, TextAdjustment.MiddleCharInvalid
                Dim textBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(text, text.Length)
                Dim invalidCharIndex As Integer = If(adjustment = TextAdjustment.FirstCharInvalid, 0, text.Length \ 2)

                textBuilder(invalidCharIndex) = AdjustmentInvalidChar

                Return textBuilder.ToString()
            Case Else
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    NameOf(adjustment), adjustment, $"Unsupported {NameOf(StackOverflow56011014.TextAdjustment)} value."
                )
        End Select
    End Function

    ''' <summary>Loads the text for the upcoming benchmark based on the text parameters.</summary>
    <GlobalSetup()>
    Public Sub LoadBenchmarkText()
        Text = TextByLengthThenAdjustment(TextLength)(TextAdjustment)
    End Sub

    <Benchmark(Baseline:=True)>
    Public Function StringIndexOf() As Boolean
        For X As Int32 = 0 To Text.Length - 1
            If ValidCharsString.IndexOf(Text.Chars(X)) = -1 Then
                'Invalid value
                Return False
            End If
        Next X

        Return True
    End Function

    <Benchmark()>
    Public Function CharOperators() As Boolean
        For X As Int32 = 0 To Text.Length - 1
            Dim c = Text(X)

            If Not (
                c = "-"c _
                    OrElse (c >= "0"c AndAlso c <= "9"c) _
                    OrElse (c >= "A"c AndAlso c <= "Z"c) _
                    OrElse (c >= "a"c AndAlso c <= "z"c)
            ) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next X

        Return True
    End Function

    <Benchmark()>
    Public Function SelectCaseChars() As Boolean
        For X As Int32 = 0 To Text.Length - 1
            Select Case Text(X)
                Case "-"c
                Case "0"c To "9"c
                Case "A"c To "Z"c
                Case "a"c To "z"c
                    Continue For
                Case Else
                    Return False
            End Select
        Next X

        Return True
    End Function

    <Benchmark()>
    Public Function SelectCaseIntegers() As Boolean
        For X As Int32 = 0 To Text.Length - 1
            Select Case Strings.AscW(Text(X))
                Case 45        REM '-'
                Case 48 To 57  REM '0' - '9'
                Case 65 To 90  REM 'A' - 'Z'
                Case 97 To 122 REM 'a' - 'z'
                    Continue For
                Case Else
                    Return False
            End Select
        Next X

        Return True
    End Function

    <Benchmark()>
    Public Function CharIsLetterOrDigit() As Boolean
        For X As Int32 = 0 To Text.Length - 1
            Dim c = Text(X)

            REM Reject non-ASCII letters for which Char.IsLetterOrDigit returns True
            If Not (c = "-"c OrElse (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) AndAlso c <= "z"c)) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next X

        Return True
    End Function

    <Benchmark()>
    Public Function HashSetContains() As Boolean
        For X As Int32 = 0 To Text.Length - 1
            If Not ValidCharsHashSet.Contains(Text.Chars(X)) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next X

        Return True
    End Function

    <Benchmark()>
    Public Function RegexMatchInterpreted() As Boolean
        Return ValidCharsRegexInterpreted.IsMatch(Text)
    End Function

    <Benchmark()>
    Public Function RegexMatchCompiled() As Boolean
        Return ValidCharsRegexCompiled.IsMatch(Text)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        BenchmarkDotNet.Running.BenchmarkRunner.Run(Of Benchmarks)()
    End Sub
End Class
```

All uppercase, lowercase, and digit characters plus two dashes happens to be a nice 64 characters, so I benchmarked against that text, 16 repetitions (1,024 characters), and 16,384 repetitions (1,048,576 characters).  I also included much shorter text that repeated the pattern `<upper> <lower> <digit> <upper> <lower> <digit> <dash>` for 16 characters.  Each text input was benchmarked with the first character invalid, the middle character invalid, and unmodified.  Here are the results I got:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.17763.437 (1809/October2018Update/Redstone5)
Intel Core i7 CPU 860 2.80GHz (Nehalem), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=2.1.602
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.1.9 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.06, CoreFX 4.6.27415.01), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.1.9 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.06, CoreFX 4.6.27415.01), 64bit RyuJIT


|                Method | TextLength |    TextAdjustment | Ratio |              Mean |           Error |          StdDev |            Median | RatioSD |
|---------------------- |----------- |------------------ |------:|------------------:|----------------:|----------------:|------------------:|--------:|
|         StringIndexOf |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  1.00 |         20.347 ns |       0.0294 ns |       0.0261 ns |         20.344 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.668 ns |       0.0125 ns |       0.0117 ns |          2.669 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.663 ns |       0.0104 ns |       0.0092 ns |          2.662 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.663 ns |       0.0192 ns |       0.0180 ns |          2.653 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.25 |          5.157 ns |       0.0083 ns |       0.0074 ns |          5.155 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.59 |         11.987 ns |       0.0766 ns |       0.0679 ns |         11.959 ns |    0.00 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  9.86 |        200.588 ns |       1.0530 ns |       0.9849 ns |        200.415 ns |    0.05 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |         16 |  FirstCharInvalid |  5.90 |        120.033 ns |       0.7760 ns |       0.7258 ns |        119.965 ns |    0.04 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.00 |        113.451 ns |       0.2279 ns |       0.2020 ns |        113.418 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.20 |         21.836 ns |       0.4759 ns |       1.3265 ns |         20.977 ns |    0.01 |
|       SelectCaseChars |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.18 |         20.772 ns |       0.0432 ns |       0.0404 ns |         20.766 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.19 |         21.136 ns |       0.7391 ns |       0.7259 ns |         20.788 ns |    0.01 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.39 |         44.811 ns |       0.0992 ns |       0.0928 ns |         44.816 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.14 |        129.857 ns |       0.3097 ns |       0.2745 ns |        129.810 ns |    0.00 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  5.55 |        629.442 ns |       3.4850 ns |       3.2599 ns |        629.455 ns |    0.03 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |         16 | MiddleCharInvalid |  3.29 |        372.947 ns |       1.9290 ns |       1.5060 ns |        372.723 ns |    0.01 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |         16 |              None |  1.00 |        246.171 ns |       0.6630 ns |       0.5877 ns |        246.267 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |         16 |              None |  0.15 |         37.253 ns |       0.0264 ns |       0.0220 ns |         37.250 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |         16 |              None |  0.15 |         37.317 ns |       0.1025 ns |       0.0959 ns |         37.289 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |         16 |              None |  0.15 |         37.297 ns |       0.1205 ns |       0.1068 ns |         37.265 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |         16 |              None |  0.34 |         84.260 ns |       0.5082 ns |       0.4505 ns |         84.219 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |         16 |              None |  0.97 |        238.560 ns |       0.5839 ns |       0.5176 ns |        238.724 ns |    0.00 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |         16 |              None |  2.44 |        599.841 ns |       2.7838 ns |       2.6039 ns |        600.461 ns |    0.01 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |         16 |              None |  1.97 |        486.225 ns |       3.1438 ns |       2.9407 ns |        486.056 ns |    0.01 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  1.00 |         20.372 ns |       0.1079 ns |       0.0901 ns |         20.339 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.662 ns |       0.0190 ns |       0.0169 ns |          2.655 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.674 ns |       0.0105 ns |       0.0082 ns |          2.674 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.660 ns |       0.0128 ns |       0.0119 ns |          2.657 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.25 |          5.145 ns |       0.0058 ns |       0.0055 ns |          5.143 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.59 |         11.979 ns |       0.0267 ns |       0.0237 ns |         11.978 ns |    0.00 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  9.85 |        200.676 ns |       0.8696 ns |       0.6790 ns |        200.660 ns |    0.05 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |         64 |  FirstCharInvalid |  5.74 |        117.095 ns |       2.0289 ns |       1.8978 ns |        117.581 ns |    0.09 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.00 |        688.376 ns |       2.1290 ns |       1.7779 ns |        688.436 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.12 |         83.431 ns |       0.2190 ns |       0.2049 ns |         83.513 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.12 |         83.191 ns |       0.4731 ns |       0.4426 ns |         83.040 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.12 |         83.101 ns |       0.2071 ns |       0.1836 ns |         83.142 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.21 |        141.536 ns |       0.3475 ns |       0.2902 ns |        141.519 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.73 |        502.879 ns |       1.6034 ns |       1.4998 ns |        502.753 ns |    0.00 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  2.45 |      1,689.088 ns |      10.5955 ns |       9.9110 ns |      1,685.374 ns |    0.02 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |         64 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.36 |        940.144 ns |       3.2392 ns |       2.8715 ns |        939.693 ns |    0.01 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |         64 |              None |  1.00 |      1,295.988 ns |      13.4363 ns |      11.9109 ns |      1,296.413 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |         64 |              None |  0.14 |        180.108 ns |       0.3761 ns |       0.3334 ns |        180.056 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |         64 |              None |  0.14 |        180.061 ns |       0.4610 ns |       0.4312 ns |        180.022 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |         64 |              None |  0.14 |        180.556 ns |       0.6100 ns |       0.5706 ns |        180.600 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |         64 |              None |  0.24 |        316.839 ns |       1.3384 ns |       1.2519 ns |        316.447 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |         64 |              None |  0.73 |        948.852 ns |       0.5484 ns |       0.4861 ns |        948.910 ns |    0.01 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |         64 |              None |  1.08 |      1,399.224 ns |       5.7519 ns |       5.3803 ns |      1,397.276 ns |    0.01 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |         64 |              None |  0.94 |      1,220.376 ns |       3.9620 ns |       3.7060 ns |      1,219.580 ns |    0.01 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  1.00 |         20.303 ns |       0.0379 ns |       0.0316 ns |         20.300 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.660 ns |       0.0115 ns |       0.0102 ns |          2.658 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.666 ns |       0.0226 ns |       0.0211 ns |          2.657 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.657 ns |       0.0068 ns |       0.0064 ns |          2.656 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.25 |          5.158 ns |       0.0233 ns |       0.0207 ns |          5.149 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.59 |         11.930 ns |       0.0097 ns |       0.0086 ns |         11.928 ns |    0.00 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  9.92 |        201.375 ns |       1.2479 ns |       1.1672 ns |        201.762 ns |    0.06 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |       1024 |  FirstCharInvalid |  5.73 |        116.445 ns |       0.9321 ns |       0.8263 ns |        116.386 ns |    0.04 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.00 |     10,606.137 ns |      99.0400 ns |      92.6421 ns |     10,629.296 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.14 |      1,492.585 ns |       3.0048 ns |       2.6637 ns |      1,491.951 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.14 |      1,496.829 ns |       5.0131 ns |       4.4440 ns |      1,495.310 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.14 |      1,496.302 ns |       3.7031 ns |       3.4639 ns |      1,495.270 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.24 |      2,542.033 ns |       7.7978 ns |       6.9125 ns |      2,542.110 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.72 |      7,639.019 ns |      27.6810 ns |      25.8928 ns |      7,635.121 ns |    0.01 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  2.26 |     23,942.868 ns |      83.0869 ns |      73.6543 ns |     23,924.171 ns |    0.02 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |       1024 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.25 |     13,233.471 ns |      25.2865 ns |      21.1154 ns |     13,226.030 ns |    0.01 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |       1024 |              None |  1.00 |     21,473.132 ns |     244.6120 ns |     228.8103 ns |     21,413.010 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |       1024 |              None |  0.14 |      2,967.014 ns |      10.5175 ns |       9.3235 ns |      2,964.323 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |       1024 |              None |  0.14 |      2,964.892 ns |       6.7969 ns |       6.3578 ns |      2,962.519 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |       1024 |              None |  0.14 |      2,964.403 ns |       4.3433 ns |       3.8502 ns |      2,962.912 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |       1024 |              None |  0.24 |      5,066.337 ns |      28.4111 ns |      26.5758 ns |      5,064.938 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |       1024 |              None |  0.71 |     15,224.153 ns |      55.8292 ns |      52.2227 ns |     15,199.419 ns |    0.01 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |       1024 |              None |  0.91 |     19,469.031 ns |      34.3800 ns |      30.4770 ns |     19,471.376 ns |    0.01 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |       1024 |              None |  0.84 |     17,932.826 ns |      56.9254 ns |      53.2480 ns |     17,905.849 ns |    0.01 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  1.00 |         20.299 ns |       0.0325 ns |       0.0272 ns |         20.303 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.660 ns |       0.0149 ns |       0.0140 ns |          2.654 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.651 ns |       0.0046 ns |       0.0038 ns |          2.650 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.13 |          2.658 ns |       0.0054 ns |       0.0048 ns |          2.657 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.25 |          5.147 ns |       0.0080 ns |       0.0075 ns |          5.148 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  0.59 |         11.938 ns |       0.0224 ns |       0.0198 ns |         11.937 ns |    0.00 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  9.91 |        201.147 ns |       1.1551 ns |       1.0805 ns |        201.236 ns |    0.06 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |    1048576 |  FirstCharInvalid |  5.69 |        115.428 ns |       0.7162 ns |       0.6349 ns |        115.431 ns |    0.03 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.00 | 10,930,247.969 ns | 121,325.8754 ns | 113,488.2991 ns | 10,914,677.344 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.14 |  1,525,854.297 ns |   4,854.7069 ns |   4,303.5712 ns |  1,526,192.285 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.14 |  1,528,810.547 ns |   3,809.7073 ns |   3,563.6026 ns |  1,528,730.664 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.14 |  1,527,016.741 ns |   5,582.1223 ns |   4,948.4060 ns |  1,527,480.566 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.24 |  2,598,319.427 ns |  10,031.3678 ns |   9,383.3477 ns |  2,599,921.875 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  0.71 |  7,800,726.302 ns |  46,636.7427 ns |  43,624.0381 ns |  7,778,250.000 ns |    0.01 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  2.18 | 23,801,565.402 ns |  48,219.3237 ns |  42,745.1745 ns | 23,794,650.000 ns |    0.03 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |    1048576 | MiddleCharInvalid |  1.23 | 13,425,490.521 ns |  20,217.6784 ns |  18,911.6290 ns | 13,432,740.625 ns |    0.01 |
|                       |            |                   |       |                   |                 |                 |                   |         |
|         StringIndexOf |    1048576 |              None |  1.00 | 21,784,053.125 ns | 188,861.2630 ns | 176,660.9426 ns | 21,774,959.375 ns |    0.00 |
|         CharOperators |    1048576 |              None |  0.14 |  3,038,770.673 ns |   2,091.4132 ns |   1,746.4247 ns |  3,039,308.984 ns |    0.00 |
|       SelectCaseChars |    1048576 |              None |  0.14 |  3,038,094.349 ns |   2,619.8388 ns |   2,450.5989 ns |  3,037,726.172 ns |    0.00 |
|    SelectCaseIntegers |    1048576 |              None |  0.14 |  3,040,074.661 ns |   4,887.7384 ns |   4,571.9936 ns |  3,039,230.859 ns |    0.00 |
|   CharIsLetterOrDigit |    1048576 |              None |  0.24 |  5,217,822.154 ns |  15,537.3365 ns |  13,773.4441 ns |  5,214,110.938 ns |    0.00 |
|       HashSetContains |    1048576 |              None |  0.72 | 15,697,332.478 ns |  19,172.8185 ns |  16,996.2042 ns | 15,692,989.844 ns |    0.01 |
| RegexMatchInterpreted |    1048576 |              None |  0.91 | 19,760,729.241 ns |  71,134.9694 ns |  63,059.2975 ns | 19,732,193.750 ns |    0.01 |
|    RegexMatchCompiled |    1048576 |              None |  0.84 | 18,231,037.500 ns |  48,200.8253 ns |  45,087.0819 ns | 18,222,987.500 ns |    0.01 |

// * Legends *
  TextLength     : Value of the 'TextLength' parameter
  TextAdjustment : Value of the 'TextAdjustment' parameter
  Ratio          : Mean of the ratio distribution ([Current]/[Baseline])
  Mean           : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error          : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev         : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Median         : Value separating the higher half of all measurements (50th percentile)
  RatioSD        : Standard deviation of the ratio distribution ([Current]/[Baseline])
  1 ns           : 1 Nanosecond (0.000000001 sec)
```

My results show that the low-level approaches of `CharOperators()`, `SelectCaseChars()`, and `SelectCaseIntegers()` were all about even with each other and significantly faster than other methods.  For all but the shortest text `HashSetContains()` was 30-40% faster than `StringIndexOf()`, and the `RegexMatch*` methods were, at best, a modest 10-15% faster in only the cases where the entire input needed to be scanned and considerably slower in all cases, though using `RegexOptions.Compiled` did help with that.

I guess that shows the "fancy" classes proposed by the answers here aren't the fastest way to go.  Of course, this all works because your valid characters reside in continuous ranges.  If, instead, you were checking against an arbitrary, well-distributed list of characters the answer very likely may have been different, but why not optimize for the requirements you have?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That's calling [`HashSet.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains) on a case-sensitive `HashSet`.  Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: What about `String.Empty` being passed to that function?

Comment: `IsValid("")` and `IsValid(String.Empty)` both return `True` for me.

Comment: So I would assume then, the user doesn't want to enter numbers, letters etc...? `If Not PredefinedCharacters.Contains(stringVal.Chars(X))` wouldn't that be what the user wants?

Comment: I defined `PredefinedCharacters` using the same string of invalid characters as the question, so you would have to ask the author that.  I don't understand what your point is here.  Have you tested this code you've downvoted?

Comment: Now I see.  The title of the question asks how to check if a character _is_ present whereas the code in the question checks that each character is _not_ present.  I missed that detail.  I will invert the boolean check in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is well suited for this kind of task. The code is simple and it should be efficient.

```
Dim regex = New Regex("^[0-9A-Za-z\-]+$")
Dim isValid = Regex.IsMatch(stringVal)
```

Comment: What kind of value(s) did you use for `stringVal`?  I added some benchmarking code and results to my answer and `Regex` was the slowest of all methods tested, even when using `RegexOptions.Compiled`.

Comment: I tested with a valid ­~40 character string containing different allowed characters. Note that the regex variable should be created only **once**, it does not need to be recreated every time we validate a string.

Comment: Yes, the benchmark creates the `Regex` instances once before any tests are run and re-uses them.  I will test again with input strings of various lengths shortly.

Comment: @BACON: Just saw your benchmark, I will trust these as I didn't do a proper benchmark myself, maybe there is a difference because of optimized build. I'll remove the part about regex being faster ;-)

Comment: I re-ran my benchmark with text of various lengths and found that `Regex` was, at best, 16% faster than the code in the question when having to scan the entirety of a string (though still slower than all other methods) and was at least twice as slow when the first invalid character was in the middle of the string, though using `RegexOptions.Compiled` did provide noteworthy improvement.  So, interesting to learn that `Regex` is not so good for performance, though it definitely wins as far as being clear and concise.